# setCustomAnimations срабатывает только на верхнем фрагменте стека

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-animation, backstack

Решил сделать рефакторинг. Изначально у всех фрагментов был отдельный layout и в общем фрагменте были только общие переменные. Решил создавать там layout с парой общих кнопок и остальной контент запихивать в наследниках. в итоге когда есть несколько фрагментов в стеке то при закрытии анимация срабатывает только с первым. Tag у каждого уникален на основе toString()

добавляют стеки в FrameLayout так:

```
fm.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left,R.anim.slide_right)
.add(R.id.container,fragment, fragment.toString())
.addToBackStack(fragment.toString()).commit();
```

удаляю так:

```
fm.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left, 
R.anim.slide_right).remove(fragment).commit();
fm.popBackStack();
```

базовый фрагмент создаю так:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout v =(LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_base_screen, container, false);
    addSubLayout(v);
    return v;
}
```

addSubLayout - метод через который наследники добавляют свои layout

Comment: скорей всего в другом ошибка, покажите весь код или выложите ссылку на сурс с указаниме где трабл, так быстрей ответить.
можете добавить в ваш fragmentManager  -> addOnBackStackChangedListener дабы подебажить и посмотреть что по стеку проходитеь верно, как правило там делают ошибки

Comment: ошибка была в toString, имя фрагмента использует спецсимволы которые в тег почемуто не перезаписывались simpleName + uid  решили проблему

Comment: кстати у вас toString одинаковых фрагментов, ну разных экземпляров будут разные, это тоже приведет к undefine, к неопределенному поведению, обычно так не делают, а ставят осмысленные теги для фрагментом, тогда со стека в дебаге легко искать

Comment: Суть была имено в том чтобы два одинаковых фрагмента в одном стеке имели  разные теги так как часто фрагменты владели разными модельными состояниями.  Вопрос решился заменой toString на getSimpleName + текущее время в мс

Comment: Нууууу в итоге вы это и сделали, просто создали уникальное имя

Comment: В принципе да, просто toString не записывался в Тег, видимо какие-то символы(@?) в нем были запрещенными для тегов.

Comment: Ну вы ответьте сами, если решили проблему. Другим будет полезно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема крылась в методе toString() его базовая реализация содержала символы не разрешенные для записи в tag. Проблема решилась заменой toString на getSimpleName + текущее время в мс.